# why I cannot unset the value of an array(PHP)

Tags: php

I want to unset a field of a two-dimensional array. I got a function like this, but it doesn't work:

```
  function excludeOldScreeningDate($array){
    foreach($array as $val){
      if($val['ref'] == 'G'){
       unset($val['screening_date']);
      }
    }
    return $array;
  }
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  What output did you expect?  What output did you get?

Comment: @JackManey: Because he's unsetting only temporary variable $val

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass elements of an array by reference:

```
function excludeOldScreeningDate($array){
    foreach($array as &$val){
        if($val['ref'] == 'G'){
            unset($val['screening_date']);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Notice the `foreach($array as &$val){` line has changed.

Answer (score 7):

Because you're unsetting only temporary variable $val

```
  function excludeOldScreeningDate($array){
    foreach($array as $index => $val){
      if($val['ref'] == 'G'){
       unset($array[$index]['screening_date']);
      }
    }
    return $array;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit the values in the array, you can read each array element by reference.  Put a `&` in front of `$val` in the `foreach`.

```
  function excludeOldScreeningDate($array){
    foreach($array as &$val){
      if($val['ref'] == 'G'){
       unset($val['screening_date']);
      }
    }
    return $array;
  }
```